# Using nowrap option, how can I make overlong lines visually recognizable?

Tags: vim

I often edit files with overlong lines. Therefore, I would prefer to `:set nowrap` to visually retain the structure better. But using `nowrap`, I live in fear of not seeing a part that is essential to whatever I edit (or worse, could change the meaning dramatically).

Is there any way to accentuate non-wrapped overlong lines (I didn't find anything from a look at the help)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the help for `listchars`:

```
extends:c Character to show in the last column, when 'wrap' is
          off and the line continues beyond the right of the
          screen.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Contrairy to what the help says, `extends:c` even works when `list` is off -- Exactly what I need!